# CSS code in ASP.NET

Tags: css, .net

Where should I put the css code for the images of /home/portfolio in Visual Studio ASP.NET project?

```
<div id="site_content" class="col-md-3">
  <ul id="gallery">
    <li>
      <a href="">
        <img src="~/images/portfolio1.jpg" width="400" height="300" />
        <p>My portfolio file 1</p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">
        <img src="~/images/portfolio2.jpg" alt="" />
        <p>My portfolio file 2</p>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I want this to be without list-style-type and to be responsive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this:

In SolutionExplorer ---> Right click to project ---> Add existing item  and then select your Stylesheet(CSS).